# Selecting uniques in MySQL across two tables?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two tables, genre and genre_apps

Genre has the following fields:

export_date
genre_id
parent_id
name

genre_apps has the following fields:

export_date
genre_id
application_id
is_primary

What I would like to do is show all the unique names within genre_apps.

I have tried this

```
SELECT genre.name from grenre inner_join genre_Apps on (genre.genre.id = genre_apps.genre.id);
```

but I get an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'genre_Apps on ( genre . genre . id = genre_apps . genre . id )  LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change

```
genre.genre.id
```

to

```
genre.genre_id
```

(note the period is replaced with an underscore)

likewise with genre_apps.genre.id. also you refer to table "grenre" which should be "genre" also "inner_join" should be "inner join". try this:

```
SELECT genre.name from genre inner join genre_apps on genre.genre_id = genre_apps.genre.id;
```